# Rails - Nested attributes views are not shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, nested-attributes

I am using join table and nested attributes for collecting list of investor interests in a separate table for investor profiles. For some reasons my view is empty and not showing the **investor_interest** text field to update. Can you please find it why? My code below.

**investor_profile.rb**

```
class InvestorProfile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :investor_profile_interests
  has_many :investor_interests, through: :investor_profile_interests

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :investor_profile_interests

end
```

**investor_interest.rb**

```
class InvestorInterest < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :investor_profile_interests
  has_many :investor_profiles, through: :investor_profile_interests
end
```

**investor_profile_interest.rb**

```
class InvestorProfileInterest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :investor_profile
  belongs_to :investor_interest

end
```

**investor profile controller**

```
def new
  @investor_profile = InvestorProfile.new
end
```

**views**

```
<%= form_with model: @investor_profile, class: 'form new-profile-form' do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
      <%= f.fields_for :investor_profile_interests do |test| %>
        <%= test.text_field :investor_interest %>
      <% end %>
   </div>
  <div class="field">
      <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'button is-primary is-normal' %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In new method, build investor_profile_interests -

```
def new
  @investor_profile = InvestorProfile.new
  @investor_profile.investor_profile_interests.build
end
```